# Fibonacci sequence - codeabbey task

Tags: php

I started solving ***codeabbey.com*** problems, and got stuck at this specific one.
I also am trying to learn Object Oriented ways of coding in PHP, I hope it wont be insanely hard to read.

---

**Problem that i have:** 
When I am working with single value of input (only two lines in 'std', 2nd one being) everything works fine.
Everything works fine with every single value I have as problem file, however, if i put entire array, it loops and times out on every single value except the last one. I put timeout after 2000 iterations for testing purposes since it keeps looping until php explode otherwise.

Is there something that I am doing wrong here? I am not sure why it works for single values but when i loop it through array it keeps timing out.

I hope I am being clear, please ask anything so I can edit this post.
Thank you!

- **[Link to problem](http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/fibonacci-sequence)**
- **[Link to std file](http://pastebin.com/0vXppmaj)**

*I cannot post more than two links, so I guess you could use your own syntax coloring.*

---

```
<?php

class Input {                                       // Reading input file from codeabbey (in this case from 'std' file on my pc)
    public $first_line = null;                      // I am using this class in every problem on the site so its more complicated
    public $data = null;                            // than required for this problem

    public function __construct($input) {           // Puting 1st line (helper) in $firstline and rest of array in $data
        $input = file_get_contents($input);
        $input = explode("\n", $input);

        $this->first_line = $input[0];

        array_shift($input);

        $this->data = $input;
    }

    public function toIntegers() {                  // Convert strings from array in integers
        $data = $this->data;                        // Didn't use this for this problem
        foreach ($data as $key=>$value) {
            $data[$key] = (int)$value;
        }
        $this->data = $data;
    }

}

class Fibonacci {                                   // Creating Fibonacci array and counting steps for problem
    private $data;
    public $hits = array();
    public function __construct($input) {           // Loading input array in class
        $this->data = $input;
    }

    public function createFibonacci($number) {      // Function: Creating fibonacci array until it reaches certain number
        $fibonacci = array(0,1);                    // Argument: Limit number up to which array is created
        $a = true;                                  // Return:   Fibonacci array
        $count = 0;
        while ($a) {

            $length = count($fibonacci);
            $count++;
            $fibonacci[] = bcadd($fibonacci[$length-1], $fibonacci[$length-2]);
            if ($fibonacci[$length-1] == $number) {
                echo "found match as $count for number $number<br>";
                $this->hits[] = $count;
                $a = false;
            }
            if ($count > 2000) {
                $a = false;
                echo 'timed! <br>';
            }
        }

    }

    public function countIndex() {                  // Function: counting index at which given number occured
        foreach ($this->data as $key => $value) {   // Arguments: --
            $this->createFibonacci($value);         // Return: index number for each number in array
        }
    }
}


$input = new Input('std');
$data = $input->data;

$fibonacci = new Fibonacci($data);
$fibonacci->countIndex();
```

Comment: Hi, can you post a var_dump($data) just before you create your Fibonacci object please ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8PZDuUsH

Var_dump of $input object, and the result of loop function after it.

Comment: I'm testing, the problem is really interesting :D

Comment: Puzzling... That script should work, not sure why it times out...

Comment: Mine doesn't time out it's super fast to process and i have :
found match as 39 for number 63245986
All others are not found, so i checked the numbers and randomly picked one of them and found it in the fibonacci number list. Also it's on the 39th occurence so i guess your algorithm can't be wrong or it wouldn't find the right nomber at the right occurence....

Comment: Ye, function $fibonacci->createFibonacci() works perfectly, it finds indexes without problem... Really strange. But it doesn't work in a loop for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**So the solution (very stupid one though):** 
Since i tried to do some foreach loops and things on new files, I accidentally noticed that var_dump of my input array gives length of string that is +1 than it should be... It turned out that i had  at the end of each line as well when i exploded the file with "/n". Copy paste thingy with my editor i presume (Netbeans).

Just changing "/n" with "/r" made file run smoothly.

```
public function __construct($input) {           // Puting 1st line (helper) in $firstline and rest of array in $data
        $input = file_get_contents($input);
        $input = explode("\r", $input);    // CHANGE \R INSTEAD OF \N

        $this->first_line = $input[0];

        array_shift($input);

        $this->data = $input;
    }
```

On **codeabbey.com** though, input "\n" works fine for their php://stdin file.

Answer (score 0):

Man i just found...It's just the numbers which are too big to be handled :)

When you type : echo PHP_INT_MAX;
It will return you the maximum integer number you will be able to handle on your server (64 bits can handle more than 32 for obvious reasons).

On my system (32 bits wamp) : PHP_INT_MAX returns 2147483647
And all the numbers on the list are bigger than this number, except the one which is found 63245986.

See what happens when the number is too big : Integer Overflow examples. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: Thats why you use http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcadd.php on strings...
also: http://pastebin.com/hDkGmCzK

It works for super large numbers ^^

Comment: Yeah but still, even if you use a native function, it's just the way every 32/64bits system work at some point the calculus has to be done.
Try to feed your list with fibonacci numbers which are under the threshold given by your PHP_INT_MAX.

I bet you it's going to work

Comment: Ye, ofcourse it works if you give integers in range. Problem is, function works well with super-large strings as well using bcadd that is enabled on codeabbey server as well, why wont it work 20 times in row is the question? You can't tell me this problem cannot be solved with PHP ^^

Comment: Well, the only thing i see is that it works for every number under the MAX_INT treshold, so your function works well, that the thing.

The only issue is with large numbers which can't be handled by the system so you have to find a workaround.

I'd suggest to slice the big numbers into 2 strings and do the calculus on numbers with twice less numbers, then compare as strings .